# get a summary/overview of large Javascript files

Tags: javascript

I have several large Javascript files that I need to document/digg into. Unfortunately I do not have any documentation whatsoever on them, and rather than opening them up one by one to check the content of each file, I was wondering if there is a tool out there that will extract a summary from a given JavaScript file.

Does there exist a tool that outputs e.g. all names of functions (if they're not anonymous for that matter)? I've been searching the net for a while, but couldn't really find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run your JS files through the jsdoc-toolkit found here: http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/

It will generate skeletal documentation (HTML) for each js file with function & global variable lists but without any actual documentation. You can then use that as a basis for managing the documentation process. :)

Comment: If the answer helped you, do accept it. Thats what keeps the community going. Tks.

Comment: Can't accept an answer within a certain amount of time the thread was originally created... Quite annoying since that answer was good, and I actually forgot all about this question afterwards :-)